# Mitchell's Embedding Theorem for not-necessarily-small categories

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

Mitchell's Embedding Theorem states that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a small abelian category, then there is a ring $R$ and a fully-faithful exact functor $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow R\mathsf{Mod}$.

To what extent does this still hold if $\mathcal{A}$ is not-necessarily-small?  Does it still hold in general?  Do we need to impose extra hypotheses?

Comment: Iirc there is a counterexample in Mitchell's book on abelian categories.

Comment: If you're only interested in proving exactness lemmas about small diagrams, then there are ways of working around the size issue. For instance, you could take the smallest abelian subcategory containing the diagram in question. Or you could pass to a larger universe, thereby making the whole category small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freyd proved in his paper [Concrenteness](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404973900315) (1973) that an abelian category which admits a faithful exact functor to $\mathsf{Ab}$ is well-powered; actually also the converse. There are abelian categories which are not well-powered, see [MO/93853](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93853). Another example is mentioned in the foreword of the tac reprint of Freyd's book [Abelian categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html) (2003) with details in his paper [Stable homotopy](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-99902-4_5) (1966): The stable homotopy category embeds fully faithfully into an abelian category (which thus is not concretizable).